# What is the advantage of using BPTT along with teacher forcing?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, recurrent-neural-network

In section 10.2.1 of deep learning book (available at deeplearningbook.org), the authors mentioned that when we have both hidden-to-hidden and output-to-hidden feedbacks in recurrent neural networks, we can use both back propagation through time (BPTT) and teacher forcing learning methods. I think the main advantage of teacher forcing is to parallelize training of different time steps, where BPTT cannot exploit such parallelization. So, what is the advantage of using both these learnings? When we are forced to use BPTT, does using teacher forcing make any difference?

Comment: Not an answer, but you might find some insights here: http://www.cedar.buffalo.edu/~srihari/CSE676/10.2.1%20TeacherForcing.pdf